# multiple google maps on same page not working in bootstrap popup modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

i have two google maps on same page in bootstrap modal i am using google maps **google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);** to load multiple maps, let me show you my code

**HTML**

```
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <h1 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Free Evaluation</h1>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-custom">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                <div id="map2" class="map2">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-custom">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>


                <div id="map" class="map2">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Java Script**

```
function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {
            lat: 43.6222102,
            lng: -79.6694881
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
        });
    }


    function initMap2() {
        var myLatLng = {
            lat: 43.6222102,
            lng: -79.6694881
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
        });
    }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap2);
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42.3605336, -72.6362989));
    });

    $('#myModal2').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42.3605336, -72.6362989));
    });
```

i am basically facing two issues!

1) map.setCentre() is not working

2) the first map loads just fine,  but the second map shows grey boxes.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/sayewerivi/edit?html,output)

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sayewerivi)

i have tried a couple of solutions in my scenario but none seems to be working! any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This's my anwser. you should declare global variable 2 map.

```
var map1, map2;
function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {
        lat: 43.6222102,
        lng: -79.6694881
    };

    map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map1,
    });
}


function initMap2() {
    var myLatLng = {
        lat: 43.6222102,
        lng: -79.6694881
    };

    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map2,
    });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap2);
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map1, "resize");
    map1.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42.3605336, -72.6362989));
});

$('#myModal2').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map2, "resize");
    map2.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42.3605336, -72.6362989));
});
```

Comment: the error is gone now! but it is still not centering

Comment: @uneebmeer, this's my code. http://jsbin.com/xonekokape/edit?html,js,output

Comment: you drag map, close and reopen? it's still not working?

Comment: i am not doing anything i am just opening it and by default it is not in centre

Comment: are you sure position you want in center isn't `42.3605336,-72.6362989`. I open google map and type exactly location, and it's center..https://www.google.com/maps/@42.3605336,-72.6362989,15z

Comment: lol! my bad basically after couple of editing etc the long and lat changed between them that caused the issue! any ways bundle of thanks for the help man! of you think question is worth it give it a upvote

Answer (score 1):

If you trigger map2 instead of map, it works. Also change map.setCenter to map2.setCenter. The reason setCenter isn't working is because you're trying to call map and map2 which are not available in the scope you're using.

```js
var map
function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {
            lat: 43.6222102,
            lng: -79.6694881
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
        });
    }

    var map2;
    function initMap2() {
        var myLatLng = {
            lat: 43.6222102,
            lng: -79.6694881
        };

        map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map2,
        });
    }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap2);
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42.3605336, -72.6362989));
    });

    $('#myModal2').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map2, "resize");
        map2.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(42.3605336, -72.6362989));
    });
```

```css
.map2{
    z-index: 1!important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBGjZxt2eYCLL56VjIFKh1PewUOWd0oGcI"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <h1 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">Free Evaluation</h1>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-custom">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               
                <div id="map2" class="map2">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-custom">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

               
                <div id="map" class="map2">

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: great! the solved the grey boxes issue! but setCentre is still not working

Comment: does setCentre work for the first and on the second map?

Comment: this  is the error!  map.setCenter is not a function

Comment: map.setCenter is a function. The problem is that map and map2 are not available outside of their respective functions. Take a look at my edit. I got it working.

Comment: It seems to be centering for me. You can even change the lat and long, and the new center shows up.